# How can I set foriegn key column in Spring JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring JPA and want to set value to a foreign key column. Here is my entities and repository.

```
    @Entity
    public class Device {

      @NotEmpty
      @Id
      private String deviceId;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="userId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
      @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
      private User user;

      //Getters and setters
    }
```

```
    @Entity
    public class User(){

      @Id 
      private String userId;
      private String userName;
      //Getters and setters
    }
```

```
    public interface DeviceRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository {

    }
```

```
    public class DeviceServiceImpl implements DeviceService {
        @Autowired
        private DeviceRepository devRepos;
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepos;

        @Override
        public void saveDevice(Device device, String userId) {
           User user = null;
           if (userId!=null) {
               user = userRepos.findOne(userid);
               device.setUser(user);
           }

           deviceRepos.save(device);
        }
    }
```

The user exists in Device table but userId column in the table does not set the value. Please help me to fix the problem.

EDIT:
I removed insertable and updatable from the annotation and now it works.
@JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="userId")

Then, this means I have to get user of the device from the User table whenever I save a device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you set [insertable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#updatable%28%29) and [updatable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#updatable%28%29) to `false` for the `user` property in your `Device` class , it will cause the persistence provider to ignore this column (`Device.userId`) when generating SQL INSERT and UPDATE statement.

Just change them to `true` or remove them as their default values are already true.

---

Update :

> this means I have to get user of the device from the User table
>   whenever I save a device?

In pure JPA , if you know the ID of the user , you can use [EntityManager#getReference(User.class , aUserId)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) to get an User instance without actually querying from DB  . But in Spring Data JPA , [it seems that this method is not supported out of the box](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-83).

Comment: Thanks, I did it already. I am worried what will affect application by removing the options.

Comment: The affect is that before the change,  you cannot change the value of the database column `Device.userId` using JPA as it is read-only .After the changes , you can change the value for this column.